# CCS3 Не расстягивается до конца фон

Tags: html, css, background

Начал изучать html, css.

Когда добавляю фон со всех сторон белые полосы. Ни те которые прокрутки, а изображение до конца не растягивается.

`Background-size` пробовал.

В гугле искал информацию, но ничего не нашёл.

вот верстка:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.intro {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110vh;
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1920x250/33ff99/555555?text=Foto) no-repeat center;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `body { margin: 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте стиль background-size со значением cover.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.intro{
  width: 100%;
  height: 110vh;
  background: url(https://artsdot.com/ADC/Photos-ImgScreen.nsf/O/P-AC7DPD/$FILE/Nature-mountains_724_.Jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>asdsadassd</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "intro">
    <div class = "container">
      <div class = "header">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```